# Jquery html() conditional based on text to change different colors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can I know how to use jQuery to differentiate the colors based on html words? is it correct code as shown below? I have tried many times and it is not working.

HTML

```
<span id="Status">TERMINATED</span>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("span#Status").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() == "ACTIVE") {
            $(this).css("color", "green");
        } else if ($(this).html() == "TERMINATED") {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying an element id in the `each()` method, you are making a mistake, because the `id` is a unique attribute, and should not be repeated more than once in the document. If you have several elements with status display, then specify unique `id`. Like this:

```
<span id="Status1">TERMINATED</span>
<span id="Status2">ACTIVE</span>
```

Or specify **Status** as a class. Like this:

```
<span class="Status">TERMINATED</span>
<span class="Status">ACTIVE</span>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("span.Status").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() == "ACTIVE") {
            $(this).css("color", "green");
        } else if ($(this).html() == "TERMINATED") {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Status">TERMINATED</span>
<span class="Status">ACTIVE</span>
```

Comment: @Hua, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try below modified code. Let me know if you have issues in this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Sample For Text Color Change</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('span#Status').each(function () {
                if ($(this).html() == 'ACTIVE') {
                    $(this).css('color', 'green');
                } else if ($(this).html() == 'TERMINATED') {
                    $(this).css('color', 'red');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <span id="Status">ACTIVE</span>
        <span id="Status">TERMINATED</span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Amit Verma, thanks for your quick reply. I have tried but it doesn't seem to work. 
Here is my code :

https://jsfiddle.net/0yjcurde/

Comment: Try now. I have modified jsFiddle. you need proper HTML which is missing in jsFiddle.